# Foursquare API request returning error on version parameter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, foursquare

I am trying to send a get request to the Foursquare developer API to get a json response of all nearby venues through the "explore" feature. The error I am getting reads,

```
{'meta': {'code': 410,
  'errorType': 'param_error',
  'errorDetail': '**The Foursquare API no longer supports requests that pass in a version v <= 20120609.** For more details see https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning',
  'requestId': '5d9f5d5fcad1b6002c61ef2c'},
 'response': {}}
```

My input code is as follows:

```
LIMIT = 50
RADIUS = 16093.4
VERSION = 'YYYYMMDD'

url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, latitude, longitude, VERSION, RADIUS, LIMIT)

results = requests.get(url).json()
```

The results output is where I am getting the error.

I have tried multiple different dates for the VERSION variable, such as '20191008' , '20181008', etc. and all give me the same error.

Comment: Looks like the "VERSION" variable needs be an actual date instead of 'YYYYMMDD' based on https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/versioning

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the current date as the VERSION in the format YYYYMMDD. In this case, you need to replace 'YYYYMMDD' with the current date. For example, today's date is 03/24/2021, so you will need to replace 'YYYYMMDD' with '20210324'. You also need to go on Foursquare and reset the CLIENT SECRET.

Comment: An example would be nice

Comment: You need to make the VERSION match the current date. For example if today's date is March 24,2021, the VERSION will be 20210324. You also need to reset the CLIENT SECRET on Foursquare.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, latitude, longitude, VERSION, RADIUS, LIMIT)
```

with

```
url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION, latitude, longitude, RADIUS, LIMIT)
```